# TextBox does not always update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Bound to the following property:

```
private string _searchString;
public string SearchString
{
    get 
    { 
        return _searchString; 
    }
    set
    {
        value = Regex.Replace(value, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);             
        _searchString = value;
        DoNotifyPropertyChanged("SearchString");
    }
}
```

The class inherits from a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void DoNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

All I want is a quick and dirty way to disallow non-numerical characters for an integer-only text box (I know it's not complete, just for demonstration). I don't want a mere notification that there is illegal text or anything, I want to discard right away all characters on input that are disallowed.

However, the TextBox is behaving weirdly. I can still enter any text I want, it will display as entered, e.g. "1aaa". Even though the property has been properly cleaned to "1" in this example, the Textbox still shows "1aaa". Only when I enter an actual digit that would cause _searchString to change does it also update the displayed text, for example when I have "1aaa2" it will correctly update to "12". What's the matter here?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like view-specific logic, so I see no reason not to use code-behind the view to control it. Personally I would implement this kind of behavior with a `PreviewKeyDown` on the `TextBox` that discards any non-numeric characters.

It probably wouldn't hurt to have something generic that you could reuse, such as a custom `NumbersOnlyTextBox` control, or an `AttachedProperty` you could attach to your `TextBox` to specify that it only allows numbers.

In fact, I remember creating an attached property that allows you to specify a regex for a textbox, and it will limit character entry to just that regex. I haven't used it in a while, so you'll probably want to test it or possible update it, but here's the code.

```
// When set to a Regex, the TextBox will only accept characters that match the RegEx
#region AllowedCharactersRegex Property

/// <summary>
/// Lets you enter a RegexPattern of what characters are allowed as input in a TextBox
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowedCharactersRegexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AllowedCharactersRegex",
                                        typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxProperties),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, AllowedCharactersRegexChanged));

// Get
public static string GetAllowedCharactersRegex(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (string)obj.GetValue(AllowedCharactersRegexProperty);
}

// Set
public static void SetAllowedCharactersRegex(DependencyObject obj, string value)
{
    obj.SetValue(AllowedCharactersRegexProperty, value);
}

// Events
public static void AllowedCharactersRegexChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = obj as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            tb.PreviewTextInput += Textbox_PreviewTextChanged;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(tb, TextBox_OnPaste);
        }
        else
        {
            tb.PreviewTextInput -= Textbox_PreviewTextChanged;
            DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(tb, TextBox_OnPaste);
        }
    }
}

public static void TextBox_OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;

    bool isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text, true);
    if (!isText) return;

    var newText = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
    string re = GetAllowedCharactersRegex(tb);
    re = "[^" + re + "]";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(newText.Trim(), re, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}

public static void Textbox_PreviewTextChanged(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        string re = GetAllowedCharactersRegex(tb);
        re = "[^" + re + "]";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, re, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

#endregion // AllowedCharactersRegex Property
```

It would be used like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         local:TextBoxHelpers.AllowedCharactersRegex="[0-9]" />
```

But as to why it won't update the UI. The UI knows the value hasn't actually changed, so doesn't bother re-evaluating the binding when it receives the PropertyChange notification.

To get around that, you could try temporarily setting the value to something else before setting it to the regex value, and raising a `PropertyChange` notification so the UI re-evaluates the bindings, but honestly that isn't really an ideal solution.

```
private string _searchString;
public string SearchString
{
    get 
    { 
        return _searchString; 
    }
    set
    {
        value = Regex.Replace(value, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);    

        // If regex value is the same as the existing value,
        // change value to null to force bindings to re-evaluate
        if (_searchString == value)
        {
            _searchString = null;
            DoNotifyPropertyChanged("SearchString");
        }

        _searchString = value;
        DoNotifyPropertyChanged("SearchString");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1064519 The UI knows the value hasn't actually changed when the PropertyChange notification is raised, so it doesn't bother to re-evaluate the binding and refresh the UI. See the update to my answer :)

Comment: If it worked this way, you'd end up with infinite loops: typing a key would change the textbox, which sets the property, which would fire the PropertyChanged event, which would update the binding, which would change the textbox, which would set the property... and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: @DanPuzey Hrrrmm that's a good point to make, I hadn't thought of that. I'm curious to test it now to see if that would actually be the resulting behavior. I'm not sure if that really is the case though, or if it would just give you a StackOverflow Exception. I know you can create infinite loops with your bindings, so WPF doesn't stop you from doing it in some cases :)

Comment: its still doesnt work, i can see that DoNotifyPropertyChanged invokes the "get", but although the correct value is returned the ui doesnt get updated. thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: I think the root of the problem is trying to control keyboard input from the ViewModel. The MVVM architecture wasn't designed with that in mind - you are going to fight the system and end up with a headache. Your initial suggestion is the best, I think.

Comment: @user1064519 It's probably because you raise the PropertyChange notification on the same thread, so once it's finished executing and the UI gets its turn to work, it only re-evaluates the last PropertyChange notification.

Comment: @Rachel: I'm not sure whether it *does* work like that (and yes, it'd be `StackOverflowException` rather than infinite loop), but I'd suggest it's unintuitive for a property setter being called by a binding to override the value being bound-in.  That's probably enough reason for it to behave that way, regardless of the technical limitations.  (I wonder if coercing values in a `DependencyProperty` helps to work around this?)

Comment: @DanPuzey - I think the purpose of coerce is essentially to convert a value from one type to another and back. For example, a string to a date and back. Your original suggestion stands - restricting user keyboard input from within the ViewModel is stepping out of the MVVM bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this has something to do with WPF's built-in infinite-loop prevention logic. As written, your logic would inform WPF that the property has changed each and every time that "Set" is called. When WPF is notified that the property has changed, it will update the control. When the control updates, it will (according to your binding) call the "Set" property again. ad infinitum. WPF was designed to detect these kinds of loops and prevent them to some degree - that's probably the trap you've ended up in.

I don't know exactly how this logic works, but I think [Rachel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589954/211627) is going to get you the best results. In general, the ViewModel (what you are binding to) should be a reflection of the View, bad input and all. The ViewModel should be able to validate the input (not knowing where it came from or how it was entered) and prevent bad input from propogating to the Model (by trasitioning to an "error state", for example).

What you are trying to do is control what the user is inputting, which is probably better left to the View logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase( _textBoxName, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

updating your XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="_textBoxName" Text="{Binding SearchString,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This forces an update from source to target, you're using a DependencyProperty and your control won't update because it knows the value while sending to the binding source.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.updatetarget.aspx